# Stop the "herokuapp.com" from appearing on the end of website

Tags: heroku, dns, web

The phrase "herokuapp.com" appears on the end of my website when I type in "myapp.com". I've purchased the domain name, and directed my dns to "myapp.herokuapp.com".

I've also set up a proper "www" alias. If I type in "www.myapp.com", then my browser shows "www.myapp.com". If I type "myapp.com", then my browser shows "myapp.herokuapp.com". How can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

That suggests you're doing web forwarding at the DNS level and not setting up a CNAME on your DNS to `appname.herokuapp.com`. Some DNS providers don't support a CNAME on the apex record like myapp.com though so it's worth checking if yours does.